# Divide the sum of each group by the grand total

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, aggregate-functions

I want to get the sum of group A and B separately, and divide each by the total sum.

I tried to use this:

```
select name, sum(qt)
from ntbl
group by name
```

| order_id | name | qt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12 |
| 2 | A | 20 |
| 3 | B | 33 |
| 4 | B | 45 |

Result should be as:

| name | qt | dv |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 32 | 0.29 |
| B | 78 | 0.70 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine aggregate and window functions together:

```
select name
     , sum(qt) as sum_qt
     , sum(qt) / sum(sum(qt)) over () * 100 as pct_qt
from t
group by name
```

Comment: so if i want to multiply the ration_qt by 100 how to do so
i did like this but didnt work
`` sum(qt) / sum(sum(qt)) * 100 over () as ratio_qt``

Comment: you can't, you need another outer query, one perk of window functions

Comment: See revised answer. The "over" is part of divisor.

Answer (score 1):

You can crossjoin another subquery that sums up all quantities

> ```
> CREATE TABLE ntbl  (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(1),
>   `qt` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO ntbl 
>   (`order_id`, `name`, `qt`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'A', '12'),
>   ('2', 'A', '20'),
>   ('3', 'B', '33'),
>   ('4', 'B', '45');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name, sum_name, ROUND(sum_name/sum_qt,2) as dv
> FROM
> (select name,SUM(qt) sum_name from ntbl group by name) q1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(`qt`) sum_qt FROM ntbl) q2
> ```
>
> ```
> name | sum_name |   dv
> :--- | -------: | ---:
> A    |       32 | 0.29
> B    |       78 | 0.71
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dcfa9ab5608044c372c4a4eb0e8858f)*